# Does implicit T& constructor of std::reference_wrapper<T> make it dangerous to use?

Tags: c++, c++11

`boost::reference_wrapper<T>` has an **explicit** `T&` constructor, while `std::reference_wrapper<T>` has an **implicit** one. So, in the following code:

```
foo = bar;
```

If `foo` is a `boost::reference_wrapper`, the code will fail to compile (which is good, since `reference_wrapper` does **not** have the same semantics of an actual reference.

If `foo` is a `std::reference_wrapper`, the code will "rebind" `foo`'s reference to `bar` (instead of assigning the value as one might mistakenly expect it to).

This could result in elusive bugs... Consider the following example:

*In version **1.0** of some hypothetical library:*

```
void set_max(int& i, int a, int b) {
    i = (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

*In a new version (**1.1**), `set_max` is converted to a template to accept integers of any width (or UDT's) without changing the interface:*

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void set_max(T1& i, T2 a, T3 b) {
    i = (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

*Then finally, in some application using the library:*

```
// i is a std::reference_wrapper<int> passed to this template function or class
set_max(i, 7, 11);
```

In this example, the library changes its implementation of `set_max` without changing the call interface. This would silently break any code that passes it a `std::reference_wrapper` as the argument would no longer convert to `int&` and would instead "rebind" to a dangling reference (`a` or `b`).

**My question:** Why did the standards committee elect to allow implicit conversion (from `T&` to `std::reference_wrapper<T>`) instead of following `boost` and making the `T&` constructor explicit?

---

**Edit:** *(in response to the answer offered by Jonathan Wakely)...*

The original demo (in the section above) is intentionally concise to show how a subtle library change could result in the use of `std::reference_wrapper` introducing bugs to an application.

The next demo is provided to show a real-world, legitimate use of `reference_wrapper` for "passing references through interfaces", in response to Jonathan Wakely's point.

- **From Developer/Vendor A**

*Something similar to `std::bind` but pretend it's specialized for some task:*

```
template<typename FuncType, typename ArgType>
struct MyDeferredFunctionCall
{
    MyDeferredFunctionCall(FuncType _f, ArgType _a) : f(_f), a(_a) {}

    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T t) { f(a, t); }

    FuncType f;
    ArgType a;
};
```

- **From Developer/Vendor B**

*A `RunningMax` functor class. Between version 1.0 and 1.1 of this imaginary library, the implementation of `RunningMax` was changed to be more generic, without changing its call interface. **For purposes of this demo**, the old implementation is defined in namespace `lib_v1`, while the new implementation in defined in `lib_v2`:*

```
namespace lib_v1 {
    struct RunningMax {
        void operator()(int& curMax, int newVal) {
                if ( newVal > curMax ) { curMax = newVal; }
            }
    };
}
namespace lib_v2 {
    struct RunningMax {
        template<typename T1, typename T2>
        void operator()(T1& curMax, T2 newVal) {
                if ( newVal > curMax ) { curMax = newVal; }
            }
    };
}
```

- **And last but not least, the end-user of all the above code:**

*Some developer using the code from Vendor/Developer A and B to accomplish some task:*

```
int main() {
    int _i = 7;
    auto i = std::ref(_i);
    auto f = lib_v2::RunningMax{};

    using MyDFC = MyDeferredFunctionCall<decltype(f), decltype(i)>;
    MyDFC dfc = MyDFC(f, i);
    dfc(11);

    std::cout << "i=[" << _i << "]" << std::endl; // should be 11
}
```

**Note the following:**

- The end-user uses `std::reference_wrapper` the way in which it's intended.
- **Individually**, none of the code has bugs or logical flaws, and everything worked perfectly with the original version of Vendor **B**'s library.
- boost::reference_wrapper would fail to compile upon upgrading the library, while std::reference_wrapper silently introduces a bug that may or may not be caught in regression tests.
- Tracing such a bug would be difficult, since the "rebinding" is not a *memory-error* that tools such as `valgrind` would catch. Furthermore, the actual site of the misuse of `std::reference_wrapper` would be within Vendor **B**'s library code, not the end-user's.

**The bottom line:** `boost::reference_wrapper` seems safer by declaring its `T&` constructor as explicit, and would prevent the introduction of a bug such as this. The decision to remove explicit constructor restriction in `std::reference_wrapper` seems like it compromised safety for convenience, something that should rarely occur in language/library design.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#689

Comment: If I recall correctly, it used to be explicit. I assume they made it implicit only because of popular opinion.

Comment: @DBRalir: #689 in the "defect report list" in the link posted by Nate Kohl appears to confirm that.

Comment: The example you provided does not do what you say it would. There is no assignment operator that takes the referenced type, which means that in the code above, in the template case, it will fail to compile and force you to extract the value *before* calling the template.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The non-explicit copy constructor allows implicit conversion from T& to std::reference_wrapper<T>. Try compiling the following in gcc or clang to see demo of this: int a=1, b=2; auto a_rw = std::ref(a); a_rw = b; std::cout << "a=[" << a << "]" << std::endl;

Comment: @etherice : What exactly is that code supposed to demonstrate/prove?

Comment: @ildjarn: It demonstrates how the implicit conversion allowed by std::reference_wrapper could lead to unexpected behavior. In the demo, the code works fine when using version 1.0. But when the end-user upgrades to version 1.1, it silently introduces a bug into the end-user's application if passing a std::reference_wrapper. The boost version (boost::reference_wrapper) would fail to compile as it does not allow such unsafe implicit conversion (it declares its copy constructor as explicit)... Try compiling the code and calling both versions of set_max with a reference_wrapper (std:: and boost::).

Comment: @etherice : Sorry, I was referring to the code in your comment to David.

Comment: @ildjarn: He stated "there is no assignment operator that takes the referenced type, which means that the code above would fail to compile." While the first part is true, the second part is not, since the T& is implicitly-converted to std::reference_wrapper<T> (via non-explicit constructor) which then allows the compiler to call operator=(std::reference_wrapper<T>&). The code in the comment demonstrates that 1) it compiles, and 2) it behaves as stated (i.e., a_rw "rebinds" to b, instead of updating the value of a).

Comment: Please fix the question to make it clear you're **not** talking about the copy constructor.

Comment: Convenience over safety.  A popular tradeoff.

Comment: Is this really a code-related question or a discussion about the c++ standard? If the latter, I suggest to close it.

Comment: You're using it wrong. If you do `MyDeferredFunctionCall<decltype(f), int&>` instead of `MyDeferredFunctionCall<decltype(f), decltype(i)>` it works as intended. Do not create lvalues of type `reference_wrapper<T>` and use `decltype` on them, use `T&` where you want a reference type, and then use `std::ref(_i)` at the last minute to pass a `reference_wrapper<T>` to the function expecting `T&`

Comment: @Walter: The question was answered by Nate Kohl (DR #689 link) but since it's a comment I can't accept it as an answer, can I?  If not, I'll post the answer myself (w/ credit to Nate) and accept it to close out this question. Sound reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason **implicit conversion** (`T&` --> `reference_wrapper<T>`) is allowed for `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, **but not** `boost::reference_wrapper<T>`, is sufficiently explained in the [**DR-689**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#689) link provided by Nate Kohl. To summarize:

In 2007, the C++0x/C++11 *Library Working Group* (LWG) proposed change #**DR-689** to section `20.8.3.1 [refwrap.const]` of the standard:

> **The constructor of reference_wrapper is currently explicit**. 
>   The *primary* motivation behind this is the safety problem with respect
>   to rvalues, which is addressed by the proposed resolution of [DR-688].
>   Therefore we should ***consider relaxing*** the requirements
>   on the constructor since requests for the implicit conversion keep
>   resurfacing.
>
> **Proposed resolution:** Remove explicit from the constructor of reference_wrapper.

It's worth pointing out:

- `boost::reference_wrapper` has [**not been relaxed**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/ref.html) in such a way, nor does there appear to be a proposal for it, which creates an inconsistency between the semantics of `boost::reference_wrapper` and `std::reference_wrapper`.
- Based on the verbiage in DR-689 (specifically the "requests keep surfacing" part) it seems likely that this change was simply viewed by the LWG as an acceptable tradeoff between safety and convenience (in contrast to its boost counterpart).
- It's unclear whether the LWG anticipated other potential risks (such as those demonstrated in the examples provided on this page), since the only risk mentioned in DR-689 was that of binding to an rvalue (as described and resolved in the previous entry, DR-688).

Answer (score 3):

> This would silently break any code that passes it a `std::reference_wrapper` as the argument would no longer convert to `int&` and would instead "rebind" to a dangling reference (a or b).

So don't do that.

`reference_wrapper` is for passing references *through* interfaces that would otherwise make a by-value copy, it's not for passing *to* arbitrary code.

Also:

> `// i is a std::reference_wrapper<int> (perhaps b/c std::decay wasn't used)`

`decay` wouldn't change anything, it doesn't affect reference wrappers.

Comment: This answer does not at all address the question posed in the original **My question: ...** section; there was no request for code review.

Comment: Jonathan: The demo was intended to be concise, but to address your point I've added a more elaborate demo that uses `reference_wrapper` the way it's intended, with the same results. Also I removed the `std::decay` comment since it really wasn't pertinent to the question anyway.

Comment: @Rollie, The "why did the committee do this?" part was already answer by the link to DR 589